# How do I add +1 every time whenever the user gets the answer correct

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Here I ask the user to Gamble and when the user's answer gets correct the code adds 1 to the database but I don't know how to keep on adding when the user gets it correct for the second time like 1 then 2 then 3 and so on. So, can someone please help me with this

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json

clients = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
Bot = discord.Client()

json_file = set()


@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('ready')


@clients.command()
async def Gamble(ctx, num):
  number = random.randint(1,3)

  if int(num) == number:
    await ctx.send("Congratulations! you won 1 Tes")
    json_file.add(1)
    print(json_file)
  if int(num) != number:
    await ctx.send('Better luck next time')
    print(json_file)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: is this on replit.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood clearly, but you want a counter as the "database" (in this case the `json_file` set).

What about user a variable `counter = 0` and then every time the answer is correct, just increment it `counter = counter + 1`.

If however, you just want to have a list of ones, change `json_file` to a list (`json_file = []`) and then append 1 instead of `add` (`json_file.append(1)`). I hope that helps. If not, just explain a little bit further what you are trying to achieve, and I am sure an answer will be found.